# Why this simple angularjs script is not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

A simple script to print the data using controller.
I don't know where i am doing it wrong..
code consists of index.html, app.js and mail-list.component.js.
mail-list.component is used to create template for view and registering the controller.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mailApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mail System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src = "angular.min.js"> //angular 2
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="mail-list.component.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--use a custom component to render the mails-->
<mail-list></mail-list>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
// Define the 'mailApp' module
angular.module('mailApp', []);
```

mail-list.component.js

```
'use strict';
// Register `mailList` component, along with its associated controller and template

    angular.
      module('mailApp').
        component('mailList',{
          template:
        '<span ng-repeat="mail in $ctrl.mails"> '+
        '<input type="checkbox"><b>{{mail.sender }}:<i> {{mail.subject}}</i></b> {{ mail.message}}</span>',

      controller: function MailListController(){
        this.mails=[
          {
            sender: 'Monu',
            subject: 'Regarding Gate',
            message:'start preparing or gate 2017 exam, dont miss this time'
          },{
                sender: 'Shiv',
                subject: 'College Over',
                message:'B.tech is over, now i am a graduate, hurrey!!'
          },{
            sender: 'Monu',
            subject: 'Regarding bag',
            message:'purchase a new bag for me '
          }

        ];
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using angular version 1.4.9, while components were introduced only in angular 1.5.*

See the [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) for more details.

Comment: i am using angular 2 on my machine, since i didn't find the online link for angular 2, so just for the sake to reference it wrote 1.4.9.

Comment: I don't think that Angular 2 has the `angular` global set. You may want to take a look at the [angular 2 quick start guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html).

Comment: This tutorial is written for Angular 1.5 so this must be the reason for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As Kazimieras said, the angular version doesn't have support for `component()`.

In addition to his guide, I recommend this [component polyfill](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component) by Todd Motto to backport components to Angular 1.3+.

Answer (score -2):

You seem to be missing an [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) attribute on the  tag.

Comment: which tag, you are talking about

Comment: its there on the html tag.